# Расстояние между элементами span

Tags: html, css

Два строчных элемента расположены друг под другом

```
<span class="company-name">COMPANY NAME</span>
<span class="slogan">short slogan goes here</span>
```

Для них заданы свойства

```
#logo .company-name {
color: #003d5a;
font-size: 24px;
```

}

```
#logo .slogan {
    color: #9a0000;
    font-size: 14px;
}
```

За счет чего подвинуть эти два элемента друг к другу по вертикали?
На отрицательные маргины они не реагируют.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.slogan{
display:inline-block;
    margin-top:-15px;
}

.slogan{
position:relative;top:-15px;
}
```

все зависит от конкретного случая.

Comment: с display:inline-block; не сработало, а с display:block; получилось. спасибо))

Comment: Это не верный ответ. Значение em может расчитываться от браузера к браузеру разительно, поэтому фиксированные значения не подойдут. Советую использовать ответ ниже.

Answer (score 1):

Для общего блока обнуляем font-size, а потом уже индивидуально к каждому его прописываем:

```
#logo {
font-size: 0;
}

#logo .company-name {
font-size: 24px;
}

#logo .slogan {
    font-size: 14px;
}
```